# Only a different subnet and a virtual IP for it seems to work out to access my IP-cam

Tags: networking, 14.04, webcam, dhcp, router

My Router IP is 192.168.1.1. DHCP-Range from 192.168.1.33 to .64 . My IP-Cam (Hikvision) is set to IP 192.168.1.100. Funny enough I can access the IP-cam only if it is on its factory default (192.0.0.64) i.e. in another subnet and if I set up a virtual IP of 192.0.0.128 for reaching that subnet over my browser.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:0 192.0.0.128
```

I can access my IP-cam over firefox. But if I change its IP on 192.168.1.100 I can't access it anymore and Ubuntu then yields very inconsistent nmaps in the console:

```
nuc@nuc:~$ nmap 192.168.1.100

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-14 14:41 CEST
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.04 seconds
nuc@nuc:~$ nmap 192.168.1.100

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-14 14:42 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.100
Host is up (0.47s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp    filtered ftp
23/tcp    filtered telnet
80/tcp    open     http
443/tcp   open     https
554/tcp   open     rtsp
7001/tcp  open     afs3-callback
8000/tcp  open     http-alt
8200/tcp  open     trivnet1
49152/tcp open     unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 17.97 seconds
nuc@nuc:~$ nmap 192.168.1.100

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-14 14:42 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.100
Host is up (0.00090s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp filtered ftp
23/tcp filtered telnet

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 15.42 seconds
nuc@nuc:~$ nmap 192.168.1.100

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-14 14:42 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.100
Host is up (0.0010s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp   filtered ftp
23/tcp   filtered telnet
7001/tcp open     afs3-callback
8000/tcp open     http-alt
8200/tcp open     trivnet1

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 53.83 seconds
nuc@nuc:~$ nmap 192.168.1.100

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-14 14:43 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.100
Host is up (0.00096s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp filtered ftp
23/tcp filtered telnet

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 15.41 seconds
nuc@nuc:~$
```

Does Ubuntu thread virtual IPs different? This is quite hilarious as I can't access the cam if it's in the same subnet and it shouldn't be on 192.0.0.64 for safety reasons. But otherwise it doesn't seem to work.
Is this caused by Ubuntu, my ipcam or my router?

Edit: The usual ping 192.168.1.100 in terminal seems to work.

There some router screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When the cam i in the same subnet and when I hit a lucky second (see nmap above) I receive sometimes following screen after putting in my admin/pwd, most of the time I hit a blank browser/firefox error though:

[image]

EDIT 2:

The ping is actually producing different results on repetition.

The first time:

```
emp@thinkpad:~$ ping 192.168.1.100
PING 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.40 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
[...]
From 192.168.1.40 icmp_seq=23 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 192.168.1.40: icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=1136 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.40: icmp_seq=25 ttl=64 time=136 ms
[...]
```

The second time:

```
emp@thinkpad:~$ ping 192.168.1.100
PING 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=6.04 ms
[...]
```

Why does Ubuntu act like that?

Here are 2 more images (I've set the IP-cam to 192.168.1.199 now and ping it in the left terminal window).

The right terminal window shows tracebacks (sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -v icmp) here:
[image]

And nmap here:

[image]

Comment: What is the network mask of your eth0 IP address ? (run ifconfig)

Comment: @Pyrophorus ' sudo ifconfig eth0:inet Address:192.168.1.33 Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6-Address: fe80::c23f:d5ff:fe64:a2f/64 '

Comment: It was a hardware (router) issue, nothing to do with Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It finally turned out that it was because my router blocked certain ports. Everything works fine now with the new router my provider sent me.